# MAMP: File showing in htdocs but not on Index of/ http://localhost:8888/ page?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, localhost, mamp

I have been using MAMP for over a year now and use Codeigniter and usually have no problems setting up a a website. Ive just completed a website and changed the base URL and .htaccess file  so it would be hosted correctly. I changed the settings back and this is the problem:

The main file shows in my htdocs folder (with many other websites held locally) but when i load the start page for MAMP and the list appears of the dfile names, they are all there apart from this file! Ive tried to re-name it, checked my config base url and this is all fine.... why would the file not show up?! The other files do and when i click on the links they work fine.

Ive also tried typing the url without the file being there and this is what i get:

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

So as you do i checked my error logs and in the apache_error.log this is the message i've received:

```
[Fri Jan 18 09:37:54 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website-name/.htaccess: <IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existance of specified modules
[Fri Jan 18 09:37:55 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website-name/.htaccess: <IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existance of specified modules
```

My .htaccess file is the same as usual...

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php
#controller, previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website-name/index.php?/$1 [L]
#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends
#the request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website-name/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Could this file be corrupt? Or my whole website in this file corrupt?
Be great if i could get some advice as i've never had this problem before

Thanks

Comment: What text editor are you using? There can sometimes be problems with .htaccess files when using a text editor that doesn't do a true return when making a new line.

Comment: I opened it using dreamweaver and i've opened it using textEdit. Ive also changed the settings through the terminal to view hidden files so i could access it so i know it's hidden if that makes sense!

Comment: If by `files` you mean the local "sites", maybe the configuration for that local site is missing or wrong. Check the `httpd.conf` and the `httpd-vhosts.conf`, if exists.

Comment: Hey @faa I've checked and they both exist and the sites are set up correctly. Could a backup and a re-installation of MAMP be any good? Ive also downloaded the live hosted version from the FTP incase the localhost version was corrupt but still no luck.

Comment: When also editing some of my pages in the website file usually i have it set up so the last modified folder is at the top and this folder is not budging!

Comment: @ShimSham1984 Well, I am not sure in this case but I I've had several problems with local servers that were corrected only by reinstalling everything. I don't think it is a .htaccess problem, though, it has nothing to do with the issue you describe.

Comment: I will backup everything and do i re-install and let you's know how it goes, typical as the site is now live but it's frustrating more than anything! Thanks

Comment: Recheck the paths in the virtual hosts before you do that. Have to be the system paths to the folders, not the URLs, and it is easy to make a mistake when setting them.

Comment: Well that was annoying: Checked everything and it was fine (host files ect) Had to re-install and move all folder back in and still no luck.

I had to resolve it by creating a new CodeIgniter file and dropping my views/controller/config files back in one at time and it's all sorted.

I updated my db file from MAMP with my old files but it's swiped off the table names from phpmyadmin even though they are there :( Good thing i have them backed up and live